# Copy/drag file from VMware and paste/drop into Outlook 2019 email

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, vmware, microsoft-outlook-2019

I realise this is quite a unique issue, but I am currently unable to copy/paste or drag/drop a file from Windows Explorer in a VMware Windows 10 guest instance directly into a new Outlook 2019 email message on a Windows 10 host machine.

Instead I have to open Windows Explorer on the host, copy/paste or drag/drop the file from the Windows Explorer on the guest... and then copy/paste or drag/drop the file from the Windows Explorer on the host into the Outlook message on the host.

It used to work with my old Windows 7 host machine and Outlook 2003, and the same VMware Windows 10 instance.

I've looked for options within Outlook 2019 to see if it's rejecting the file (because it's not from the same machine, etc) but I can't find anything obvious

To be clear, the ability to copy/paste and drag/drop between the guest and host is working correctly... it's purely the ability to go straight from the guest into Outlook that's failing.

To be honest, this isn't the biggest issue in the world and I'm not expecting much of a response, but if anybody has any ideas please let me know.

Comment: I don't have VMware to help test this issue. Can you copy and paste content to other Office application? Like Word or Excel?

Comment: @Perry - thanks for the response.  I hadn't tried it, but no: Word/Excel are also the same, c/p and d/d do not work.  As I say, not the biggest issue in the world, just rather annoying when you're used it working

Comment: let's repair office to see the results. To do this, please go to Control Pane > Programs and Features. Right click your Office suit and then choose Change. Click Repair.